# How do I make my discord bot say something after its prefix is run?

Tags: discord.js

If I'm being more specific I mean if I said n!say (text) the bot would just say in the channel (text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a very simple way to do it,
when the user sends the prefix and command it just splits it off and returns the message.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
// Set the prefix
const prefix = "!";

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});
 

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command == "say"){ // set the command
            message.channel.send(args);
  }
});
 
client.login("Bot Token Here");
```

This was taken from the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/general/welcome).